# How to centre webkit scrollbar using css

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

Hi I'm trying to centre a webkit scrollbar to the center of my page above my content. I want it above my content too. I have added an image of the wireframe of what I am trying to achieve:[Wireframe Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7oFV.png)

```
/*VERTICAL SCROLLBAR*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
z-index: 99999;
 width:20px;
 background:#222;

  
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {

  background: rgba(0,155,221,1); 
  box-shadow:0 -100vh 0 100vh rgba(0,155,221,1);
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of what you've got so far

Comment: What have u tried so far? U should provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some hints so you can try yourself:

1. Hide the original scrollbar.
2. Create a div and place it in the center of your page.
3. Make a JS function which calculates how much the user has scrolled.
4. Change the height of the div according to the value you get.

Some important things to know:

1. `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` - Returns the full height of page
2. `window.pageYOffset` - Returns how many pixels the user has scrolled.
3. You can get the ratio by `(scrolledHeight/totalHeigth)*100` and set it as height in `%`.